# Ingresar informacion en clase php y almacenarla para seguir ingresando

Tags: php, class

quisiera separar montos de mis finanzas e irlos sumando segun el tipo de dato.
Mi Logica:

```
class aislarFinanzas{
$tipo;
$monto;
function sumar($tipo,$monto){
$tipo = $tipo + $monto;
}
function getTotal($tipo){
  return suma_de_los_totales_del_mismo_tipo;
 }
}
```

y para invocarlo e pensado en esto:

```
$addMoney = new aislarFinanzas();
$addMoney->("efectivo",100); // agrego 100 a efectivo
$addMoney->("tarjeta",300.20); // agrego 300.20 a tarjeta
$addMoney->("efectivo",500);  // agrego 500 a efectivo
$addMoney->("tarjeta",100.20); // agrego 100.20 a tarjeta
$addMoney->("transferencia",500); // agrego 500 a transferencia
```

y si quiero saber la suma de todos los efectivos hacer esto:

```
echo $addMoney->getTotal("efectivo");
```

esa es mi logica pero no sabria volverlo codigo, si alguien pudiera ayudarme a hacerlo funcionar se les agradeceria bastante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues no era tan dificil pasarlo a código, tan solo tenias que probarlo.

A mi me ha quedado así:

```
class aislarFinanzas {
    public function sumar($tipo, $monto) {
        $this->$tipo[] = $monto;
    }
    public function getTotal($tipo){
        return array_sum($this->$tipo);
    }
}

$addMoney = new aislarFinanzas();
$addMoney->sumar("efectivo",100); // agrego 100 a efectivo
$addMoney->sumar("tarjeta",300.20); // agrego 300.20 a tarjeta
$addMoney->sumar("efectivo",500);  // agrego 500 a efectivo
$addMoney->sumar("tarjeta",100.20); // agrego 100.20 a tarjeta
$addMoney->sumar("transferencia",500); // agrego 500 a transferencia

print_r($addMoney);
echo $addMoney->getTotal("tarjeta");
```

Eso te devuelve:

```
aislarFinanzas Object
(
    [efectivo] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
            [1] => 500
        )

    [tarjeta] => Array
        (
            [0] => 300.2
            [1] => 100.2
        )

    [transferencia] => Array
        (
            [0] => 500
        )

)
400.4
```

Gracias a A.Cedano por la aclaración en los comentarios.

Comment: Tu código no es correcto, la POO debe ser pensada respetando la realidad de las cosas, y eso no ocurre aquí, tú mezclas una propiedad `tipo` con una propiedad `monto`, en cuanto este programa avance solo un poquito en complejidad vas a tener tremendo lío. Y es que no, no y no, un `tipo` no es un `monto`. Probemos a agregar complejidad, mínimamente: *quiero saber cuántas operaciones hubo, sólo de `efectivo`*, tu clase sucumbirá ante ese requerimiento.

Comment: @A.Cedano no se, la pregunta no pedia eso, y siempre me baso en lo que piden y en el codigo que tienen para no liarles con otros posibles escenarios, que ya se los encontrarán cuando sea necesario y ya modificarán el código acorde a ello en ese momento. Este OP apenas ha puesto un poco de pseudocódigo y he realizado casi el mismo esfuerzo que el en contestarle... y si me apuras quizas un poco más :-)   No voy a darle una lección magistral de como realizar una clase con todos las posibles opiniones contradictorias que todos podemos tener. ¿Y esa complejidad que dices como la solucionarias tu?

Comment: Te entiendo, pero lo que has hecho aquí es grave, porque asignas a una propiedad el valor destinado a otra propiedad, por eso me permití el comentario, un poco duro quizá, pero es que el error es grave y eso puede llevar a cualquiera, especialmente si está iniciando, a no entender siquiera los fundamentos de la POO. La complejidad que menciono la solucionaría guardando un array con cada operación (tipo y monto) y luego contando en ese array los que sean del tipo tal. Y es que además, imagina más de una operación en cada tipo, algo que es normal en este tipo de cosas.

Comment: Bueno, he modificado mi respuesta... mientras me estabas contestando ya he ido pillando la idea del array, que supongo que te referias a lo que acabo de hacer ahora.  Aún así, si bien quizás estructuralmente te puede parecer una calamidad lo que hice antes, yo es que tiro por lo práctico a veces y si funciona lo doy por bueno, aunque después pueda arrepentirme y deba reescribir todo (no seria la primera vez, jeje, si tu supieras lo que llevo meses haciendo...)

Comment: El nuevo diseño es mucho más flexible y más a acorde a la POO. Supongamos que ahora a quien te pidió diseñar ese programa se le antoja que quiere también guardar la fecha de cada operación o cosas así, pues este código es mucho más adaptable a eso, mientras que antes, no lo era. O, otro requerimiento normal, que esa clase sepa manejar débitos / créditos ... pues también, el código, al haber pensado en un array, ya es más flexible... Cuando la cosa se complique, quizá haga falta crear una clase `OperacionBancaria`, y tu array se convertirá en objetos de ese tipo sin mayores traumas.

Comment: amigo @A.Cedano lo que puse aca no es un codigo "funcional" o "real" es como dice masterguru solo un pseudocodigo que quiere decir algo literal para usar como referencia de lo que debe ir alli mas no es un intento de codigo funcional

Comment: muy agradecido @masterguru por tu comentario, me sirvio de mucho y funciona como queria, que bueno que existan programadores como tu dispuestos a ayudar. exitos

Comment: @AndreMateoChavez la intención de mis comentarios era que el código sugerido en esta respuesta sea mejorado, como así ha sido de hecho. Me alegro de que hayas podido resolver el problema y además aplicando un estilo mucho más conforme a la POO y por consiguiente más flexible. Recuerda que aparte de aceptar la respuesta, también la puedes valorar positivamente haciendo clic sobre la **flecha gris que apunta hacia arriba**, en la parte superior izquierda de la misma. Un saludo.

Comment: @A.Cedano agradesco tu comentario amigo, muchas gracias tambien al final del cuento la idea de esta pagina es que nos ayudemos entre todos